# All requests cancelled with custom dupefilter scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a webshop where each product has multiple variants. Each variant has a URL(i.e. `10050545/V009`). However, on all individual variant URL's, all other variants can also be crawled. This means the spider really only needs to visit one variant.

To do this, I tried implementing a `Dupefilter` that removes the variant ID from the URL. I assumed this would result in the first request to, for example, `NL/10050545/V009` goes through, but `NL/10050545/V010` does not.

What it actually did, is letting the requests through, but it looks like they are canceled for some reason. The one thing I'm sure of is that the callback isn't called.

Of course, I could just check this before sending the request, but a `DupeFilter` seems prettier :)

```py
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter


class Dupefilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        if 'product/' in request.url:
            # NL/10050545/V009 > NL/10050545/ where V009 is variant id
            request = request.replace(url='/'.join(request.url.split('/')[:-1:]))
        return super().request_fingerprint(request)
```

Relevant Scrapy stats:

```
'dupefilter/filtered': 40
'response_received_count': 27,
'scheduler/dequeued': 52,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 52,
'scheduler/enqueued': 52,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 52,
'request_depth_max': 26,
```

And the requests are super simple:

```py
for href in res.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"-product-status-ACTIVE")]/@href').getall():
    url = response.urljoin(href)
    self.logger.debug(f"Visiting {url}")
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)
```

Logs:

```
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [sloggi] INFO: Found 265 products on category page  (url https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/products/NL_sloggiPROD?6))
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [sloggi] DEBUG: Visiting https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10018381/0003
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [sloggi] DEBUG: Visiting https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10018381/0004
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10018381/0004> (referer: https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/products/NL_sloggiPROD?6)
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [sloggi] DEBUG: Visiting https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10018381/0034
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10018381/0034> (referer: https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/products/NL_sloggiPROD?6)
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [sloggi] DEBUG: Visiting https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10004713/0003
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [sloggi] DEBUG: Visiting https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10004713/0004
2020-10-22 21:11:48 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/product/NL_sloggiPROD/10004713/0004> (referer: https://b2b.triumph.com/webstore/v2/products/NL_sloggiPROD?6)
```

Comment: Particularly I disagree with this design decision, it seems quite a better choice to filter this in the spider itself. However that's beside the point, so... what do you mean that requests are cancelled? From the stats, requests are clearly getting filtered, are **ALL** of the requests filtered? Can you share an execution log?

Comment: I have to disagree with the past comment's disagreement and say that it seems to me to be a really elegant use of the Scrapy dupefilter feature :). Have you ever tried to enable the `DUPEFILTER_DEBUG` setting and see what it shows?

Comment: I've added a part of the logs. Looks like this confirms that the initial request isn't filtered out by the dupe filter, but the callback isn't called.

When I use a debugger, it also shows that the request does get enqueued. To me, it looks like it gets cancelled there somewhere, but I'm not really familiar with twisted, so I'm not sure.

Comment: From what you've shown, it doesn't seem like the dupefilter is the problem. How are you determining your callbacks are not being called?

Comment: Breakpoint on the function.

That makes sense, yes, but when using the default dupe filter everything works fine. Switch it to this custom one and it does this.

Comment: `response_received_count` seems to indicate several responses are successfully received. I agree that it looks like your duplicate request filter is not the issue here. Any chance you can produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?